# referencing to an second array

Tags: java, arrays

I have two different arrays

```
String[] student_name = {"Joe", "bryan", "moe", "zoe"};
String[] favColour = {"Blue", "Black", "White"};
```

How would I assign a colour to a student in a way where i if i reference back to a student i would be able to get the details of there favourite colour as well?

For example if i ever wanted to change a students favourite colour via an user input

I know that i can print the `favColour` and `student_name` by
`student_name[0]` and `favColour[0]` outputing `Joe Blue`

But i wont be refer back to Joe Blue in the future cause Joe and Blue variables arnt connected

**edit** i already have an for loop where i can now enter the amount of students and there names

```
 String student_name[] = new String[totalstudents];

for(int i = 0; i < student_name.length;i++)
{

    System.out.println("Enter Student Names: "+i);
    student_name[i] = in.nextLine();
}
```

how would i assign a colour to each student or even set an default colour for all the students?
Thanks

Comment: You could use `Map`s where you can map from a color to students and from a student to a color. But you would probably be better off with your own `class` which has a `studentName` and `color` field

Comment: Try using a `HashMap`. Maybe it might help

Answer (score 2):

*A* way is to use a map that maps from the user name to the color.

```java
Map<String, String> studentFavouriteColor = new HashMap<>();
studentFavouriteColor.put("Joe", "Blue");
studentFavouriteColor.put("Zoe", "Red");
```

Then you can get the favorite color of a student by using the student as a key.

```java
String joesFavouriteColor = studentFavouriteColor.get("Joe"); // Gives "Blue".
```

---

The better and object oriented way is to create a class for the concept student and have the favourite color as a field.

```java
public class Student {
    public String name;
    public String favouriteColor;
    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    };
}
```

Then you can set and get the favourite color of student objects.

```java
Student joe = new Student("Joe");
joe.favouriteColor = "Blue";
Student zoe = new Student("Zoe");
zoe.favouriteColor = "Red";

String joesFavouriteColor = joe.favouriteColor; // Gives "Blue".
```

Comment: i need a way to use arrays has i have a for loop where i can enter the number of students and there names

Answer (score 0):

you can either choose to use a matrix:

```
String[][] students = {{"Joe","Blue"},{"Bryan","Black"},{"Moe","White"}};
```

or you can use a complex data structure, like hashTable

```
HashTable<String, String> students = new HashTable<String,String>();
students.put("Joe","Blue");
students.put("Bryan","Black");
```

Comment: I would recommend to use a simple `HashMap`, `HashTable` is `synchronized` which is probably not really needed in the case OP mentioned